# should I use OpenGL 2.0 or 1.0 with libgdx?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

So I've been using libgdx for a few weeks just to check what I can do, now I remember reading about the use of OpenGL 1.0 and 2.0. I am wondering what exactly is the difference between the 2 when using it with libgdx of course, can I just use OpenGL 2.0 for my projects and not worry about anything or is there some cons about it? So far I have only used 1.0, also I read about problems with compatibility when using OpenGL 2.0 is it true? I am interested about the compatibility of my future projects so would it be okay to just use OpenGL 2.0?

EDIT:
I am sorry I am talking about OpenGL ES 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: Are you talking about OpenGL ***ES*** 1.0 vs. 2.0, or desktop GL 1.0 vs. 2.0? Because ES and desktop GL aren't the same thing.

Comment: I am sorry yes OpenGL ES 1.0 and 2.0

Comment: "I read about problems with compatibility when using OpenGL 2.0 is it true" - you read this where? You should stick to 1.0 for the sake of compatibility only if you actually need said compatibility; it's impossible to figure out whether you'll need it without knowing what "compatibility" means in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's some cons about OpenGL ES 2.0: Not every phone supports it already. I have a simple rule to decide use 2.0 or 1.0: If you wanna create ONLY 2D game, use 1.0. On contrary, if 3D game is in your favor, you have to use 2.0.

Besides, you have to decide from the beginning, or else you'll suffer from their inconsistance.